# Is there any nginx --with-http_geoip_module CentOS repository?

Tags: nginx, centos, repository

I am looking for nginx repository that contains package built with **--with-http_geoip_module** and has **mainline (1.7.x currently)** version of the package.

atomic repo contains only 1.6.x stable line.

CentALT repo is not very stable so I'd like not to use it.

Compiling nginx from source is not an option.

Do you know any such repositories?